# Yocto: cannot build meta-mono

Tags: xilinx, yocto, openembedded

I'm trying to build an embedded system with yocto poky. My layers are:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/dev/microzed/meta \
  /home/dev/microzed/meta-yocto \
  /home/dev/microzed/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/dev/microzed/meta-xilinx \
  /home/dev/microzed/meta-mono \
  "
```

with git clones:

```
git clone -b master git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git ~/microzed
git clone -b master git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-xilinx ~/microzed/meta-xilinx
git clone -b master git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-mono ~/microzed/meta-mono
```

with `bitbake core-image-minimal` it all compiles and runs - but no mono.

So if I try to bitbake mono: `bitbake core-image-mono` it fails with the error:

> ERROR: Required build target 'core-image-mono' has no buildable
>   providers. Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was:
>   ['core-image-mono', 'mono-helloworld', 'mono', 'libgdiplus', 'giflib']

not sure how to resolve this. I don't actually need libgdiplus either... :/ in previous versions it was easy to remove, but the current master seems to have the dependency in quite a few places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requires meta-oe

```
git clone -b master git://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded ~/microzed/meta-openembedded
```

plus the layer:

```
    /home/dev/microzed/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
```

you can compile console-only build with:

```
bitbake core-image-mono-console
```